# How is “Parameter” pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

Is it /paˈraːmetɐ/ or /paraˈmeːtɐ/?

In other words, which syllable is stressed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As it would be more logical to pronounce this compound loanword from Greek  stressed on the first syllable of *"meter"* this is not the case in standard German where the second syllable will be emphasized:

> **paˈʀaːmetɐ** (IPA) - Par**a**meter

Listen also to this sound file found on [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Parameter): [Parameter](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/De-Parameter.ogg)

The following dictionaries list it emphasized on the second syllable:

- [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Parameter)
- [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Parameter&view=1) including sound file
- [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Parameter)
- [Farlex Free Dictionary](http://de.thefreedictionary.com/parameter)

Of course regionally the pronunciation of any word differs very much. You may find dialects that would emphasize the first syllable, or others that put emphasis on the third syllable of *"parameter"*.

Comment: You are wrong: You can pronounce the 2nd syllable as well as the 3rd: par*A*meter is a fine as param*E*ter. None of those two posibilities is better or worse then the other. I prefere param*E*ter, but par*A*meter is absolutely correct too.

Comment: "You are wrong" sounds quite blunt. Takkat did list 4 different sources to back his statement... that is more reference than most of the other answers in German Stackexchange give...  I agree with your point, that other pronunciations are possible and valid also... I just didn't like the harsh tone

Comment: @Emanuel: I am a native german speaker living in Austria (born in Graz, living in Vienna). I am 47 years old and speak german since ever. I studied physics where you have lots of parameters. "Parameter" is a word that I did hear and use many tenthousand times in german language. I don't need to look into a lexicon to find out what syllable has to be stressed. I did hear is so often! If Takkat says only one possibility is wright, and if he can show up with many sources, then it just means that they all are wrong. Fact is: Paramater can be spoken as Par*A*meter as well as Param*E*ter.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: this may well be true for Austrian German. A reference (maybe an Austrian dicitionary?) would be cool!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Cannot agree with your justification. Just because there are many people who pronounce it differently doesn't make it right. Many people also say "diesen Jahres" and yet it's wrong. I'm also in a field where the word "Parameter" is used very often (building automation), and all people agree that "ParAmeter" is correct. One of our largest customers is from Austria and also pronounces it like this. But then, there are also people who think that "Schraubendreher" is the correct word for screw driver. Anyway it is not nice to call someone wrong without backing up your claim.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Note that I'm not calling you definitely wrong. But saying "Fact is: X" doesn't make X a fact, and saying that all the given sources are wrong doesn't make them actually wrong, unless you have at least one serious source that says so (and then we have a problem, since we have contradicting sources).

Comment: When people are talking about the rules of languages, they often mistake what is the casue and what is the effect. The rules of grammar and the rules of pronunciation are NOT the cause of how people are talking. Children don't have a clue of those rules, and still they can speak. Even many adult speakers don't have the ability to explain why they pronounce words the way they do. The rules are the effect. Usage of language by native speakers is the cause. The rules you can read in schoolbooks are the attempt to explain why language is used as it is used.

Comment: People don't speak the way they do because there are rules. The way of speaking is the cause, the rules are the effect. This is only true for natural languages, not for constructed like Esperanto, and this is the reason why there exist so many exceptions to almost all rules of natural languages.
I give you an other example: I often can hear speakers in TV useing Plusquamperfect in a "wrong" manner. They say things like: "Gestern war es sehr heiß gewesen." which is grammaticaly wrong. It schould be "Gestern war es sehr heiß" or "Gestern ist es sehr heiß gewesen."

Comment: But more and more people use the "wrong" construction. Is it still wrong if everybody uses it? Or what about "Wenn ist würde-los?" Today everybody builds german if-sentences using "würde" although it is wrong if you believe school-books and grammar-guidebooks. I say those guidebooks are wrong if they adhere to rules that are not used by living people. And I also say that it is wrong to state that there is only one "correct" way to pronounce the word "parameter".

Comment: @Hubert (also from Graz...) parAmeter is universally used among mathematicians and people who have had an overdose of education in Latin and Greek. ParamEter seems to be used by 90% of software engineers and 80% of computer scientists, though.

Comment: There is a simple reason for _Parámeter_ being considered “right”: Words borrowed from Ancient Greek usually are stressed according to either Greek or Latin grammar rules in German, and in this particular case both coincide, stressing the second syllable.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, both versions are admissible. If you stress the `e` instead of the second `a`, that's perfectly fine, at least in common speech.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @Takkat: Unfortunately, the internet doesn't seem to be on my side. All I can say is that I'm used to hearing (and using) both versions in common speech. It could be technically wrong -- but then again, language is defined foremost by its usage. So, this post should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

I am impressed by the search for sources Takkat conducted, but I hope they will forgive me if I scold them harshly and friendly at the same time for this:

> <strike>As it would be more logical to pronounce this compound loanword from Greek stressed on the first syllable of "meter"</strike>

But, let us keep their Ansatz for exploring the Greek roots and let us look closer! Below I juxtaposed Greek roots with German derivatives. I don't use Greek accents, which were a late invention anyway, because I can't typeset them. Instead, I indicate the location of the ancient tonal accent (coinciding locally with the modern Greek stress accent) by use of bolder typeface.

ΠΑΡ**Α**ΜΕΤΡΟΣ : Par**a**meter

ΔΙ**Α**ΜΕΤΡΟΣ : Di**a**meter

ΠΕΡ**Ι**ΜΕΤΡΟΣ: Per**i**meter

Thus, indeed, Takkats method supports what they sought to support!

Fit of pedantry:
I intentionally omitted similar examples with different Gender.

Comment: This seems like an (extensive) comment to me, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @chirlu well, it does accomplish a lot towards answering correctly, but I allow you and Takkat to delete it and add it to Takkats answer.i got comments on my first day. Since those I am reluctant to edit extensively. I allow you to take bold action. I am not doing this  for the points:)

Comment: I think that this is a nice example of convolution. *Meter*, and therefore also *Kilometer, Zentimeter* etc. are stressed the same way (English doesn’t: *kilómetre, centimétre, métre*); *Barometer* and *Thermometer* are devices that measure things — I believe that *-meter* is a suffix here, added to what is to be measured. The *Parameter* doesn’t measure.